# Get count orders from previous week and substract for this week sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I had an sql getting the number of orders this week. My sample query below:

```
SELECT products.name,
   (SELECT COUNT(orders.product_id)
   FROM orders
   WHERE orders.product_id = products.id 
   AND DATE(orders.order_date) >=  [from] AND DATE(orders.order_date) [to]) as total_orders
FROM products p;
```

Now I want also get the total orders from previous week then get total orders from last week substract the orders from this week.

Results would be this

| Products | Total Orders This Week | Difference from last and current week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scissors | 6 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation.

A pattern:

```
SELECT SUM(orders.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE) this_week,
       SUM(orders.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) prev_week
FROM orders
WHERE orders.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
```

The query uses implicit aggregation (there is no GROUP BY - so the whole source rowset is treated as one group).

The conditions used returns either 0 or 1 depends on the checking result, so `SUM()` acts as counting the amount of TRUE checks.

Additional WHERE excludes the rows which will produce FALSE for all conditions, and eliminates excess checkings.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with this one since I gonna translate it to laravel query builder.

Answer (score 1):

you could do a function to get those totals. The function will receive
`date1` when starts that week, and `date2` when finish that week

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION TOTAL_ORDERS_FROM
(
    date1 DATE,
    date2 DATE
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE totals INT;
    
    SET totals = (
        SELECT COUNT(orders.product_id)
        FROM orders
        WHERE orders.product_id = products.id 
        AND orders.order_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
    );
    
    
    RETURN s;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then in your query you only call your function 2 times, the first to get current week orders and the second get the difference between current and last week.

```sql
SELECT products.name,
    TOTAL_ORDERS_FROM('10/10/2022','16/10/2022') as 'Total Orders This Week',
    (TOTAL_ORDERS_FROM('10/10/2022','16/10/2022') - TOTAL_ORDERS_FROM('3/10/2022','9/10/2022'))as 'Difference from last and current week'
FROM products p;
```

Comment: You use date literal format which is not correct in MySQL. You may use immediate `RETURN (SELECT ..)` and do not use BEGIN-END, additional variable and DELIMITER. Also the function may need in characteristic specifying (depends on current SQL Mode).